# Suitable Layout For GetContentPane When Working With Card Layout JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I just started to create my java GUI using pro Window Builder, the JFrame and getContentPane panel was created by default, what layout is proper for getContentPane before i proceed to create another mainPanel with card layout? by default, getContentPane is set to border layout but i cant adjust my mainPanel resolution size with the that getContentPane layout. i can only edit after i set getContentPane layout to null layout. but from what i read using null layout is not recommended.

[image]

Comment: The BorderLayout is the proper layout to use when adding a panel using a CardLayout. Just make sure you pack() the frame after adding all the components and the frame will be displayed at the preferred size of all the added components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am prefer to use MIG Layout as it give me more control and freedom to adjust my card layout